# How sensitive is Tiny Encryption Algorithm (TEA) to the magic numbers?

Tags: encryption, tea

If I needed to implement an encryption algorithm from memory, chances are I would try to implement: TEA 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm

How sensitive is it to the magic number? If I replace it with a random value is security expected to be severely diminished? 
What about the rotations? Which rotations numbers are safe? Are there clear requirements for them?

Comment: [Delta was chosen as NUMS from the golden ratio (original paper PDF)](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=C08E8409ADF484095568965A1EBF3E5E?doi=10.1.1.45.281&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: Yes, I saw that which suggests it was selected for "nothing up my sleeve" and a random number would do just as well. There isn't much on analysis there just ampirical number of rounds for diffusion.

Comment: If you're going to mess with $\phi$, I would be inclined to use the entire (unique) value across the 64 rounds. It would probably do wonders for the related key weakness.